# How to Update Layout Page content from Child Using mvvm in Uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a use case where I need to update ellipse property(user control) of layout from a child page which is I am calling using a frame. Can anyone please suggest, how to update the layout page user control data from the child page view model?I have tried to visual tree etc, without luck,
testcontrol.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Fill="MediumPurple" Width="{Binding Radius,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="{Binding Radius,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

//code behind of user control

```
public sealed partial class testControl : UserControl,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public testControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private double _btnWidth = 50;

    public double Radius
    {
        get { return _btnWidth; }

        set
        {
            _btnWidth = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Radius"));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

//Layout.xaml

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="Layout Page" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <myControl:testControl  />
    <Frame x:Name="LayoutPageFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to continous update of Radius from child page view model(which i will navigate from frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out the sample code, I suggest the following.

**RootControl.xaml.cs**

Change the `Radius` to a dependency property:

```
public double Radius
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(RootControl), new PropertyMetadata(50.0));
```

**RootControl.xaml**

Use `OneWay` binding only.

```
<Ellipse Fill="MediumPurple" Width="{x:Bind Radius, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Height="{x:Bind Radius, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**Layout.xaml**

Because your target page is wrapped in a `Frame`, you need to access its data context through `Content` of the frame. Again note to use `OneWay`:

```
<controls:RootControl Radius="{Binding ElementName=LayoutPageFrame, Path=Content.DataContext.SliderValue, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="RootControl"/>
```

**ChildPage.xaml**

Replace all usages of `EllipseDimention` with `SliderValue`. Make sure all bindings are `OneWay`, except for the `Slider`, which should be `TwoWay`.

**ChildPage.xaml.cs**

Remove the `EllipseDimention` property, keep only `SliderValue`:

```
public int SliderValue
{
    get
    {
        return _sliderValue;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _sliderValue, value);
    }
}
```

Also note you don't have to pass the property name as the last parameter - this is automatically done by the compiler thanks to `[CallerMemberName]` attribute used in the `Set` method.

Comment: Hi Martin i have made changes as per your suggestion,but not yet able to update value user control from the child page.I have to update the User control Radius from a page view model which is rendered in page frame.?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please? Ideally a GitHub repo :-) ?

Comment: Hi Martin please find git repo here https://github.com/dksingh605/UwpDemos.git in ChildPage.XAML there is comment section please uncomment and try to get data from layout to child.I have tried but not worked.Please take a look

Comment: @DharmendraSingh I have checked your code and got it to work. See my updated answer which contains all changes required.

Comment: Hi Martin, this works now we are able to pass data from child to layout. My Scenario is from layout to child also.ie user should able to set slider value of child page from root control radius. Can you please help me with this also?

Comment: How should the user change the radius on the root control?

Comment: From changing the size of the ellipse defined in root control

Comment: I suppose you could just set the default value for the Radius property and the default value for the View Model's property to the same value?

Comment: Hi Martin we are able to bind data two way now (ie from Layout to Child,Child to Layout)i am committing the complete code. Martin your suggestion helps a lot. Thanks again.Git Repo of complete Poc  https://github.com/dksingh605/UwpDemos.git

Comment: Awesome :-) . Glad it helped!